# Replace string before dot with another string

Tags: c#

I am having a string like below :

```
String str = "abc.History_logs";
```

Now I want to replace string before dot with this fixed string : **apc**

So final string will be like this :

> apc.History_logs;

**Code :**

```
String str = "abc.History_logs";
string final = string.Join('apc.',str.Substring(str.IndexOf(".") + 1).Trim()); //error:invalid arguments for join
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`string.Concat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string final = string.Concat("apc.", str.Substring(str.IndexOf(".") + 1).Trim());
```

I don't think there is an overloaded method exists for `String.Join(String, String)`

Comment: This worked.Thank you so much for the help and please keep helping like this :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex

```
Regex.Replace(str,@".*?\.","apc.")
```

Answer (score 2):

This Regex pattern will ignore the dot itself, allowing you to substitute whatever you want without having to remember to reinsert the dot:

```
Regex.Replace(str, @".*?(?=\.)", "apc");
```

Answer (score 2):

[string.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx) method looks more suitable for this

```
    string source = "abc.d";
    string target = "apc";
    source = source.Replace(source.Split('.')[0], target);
```